# trace TLM port connections using UVM ML wiith Specman and SV

Tags: specman

I am using UVM-ML on Incisive, and cannot figure out why data is not passing between my SV collector and e scoreboard. How can I see which TLM ports are connected, and in general debug ML environments?

Answer (score 1):

Uvm_ml_phase -run connect
Uvm_ml_print_tree
Uvm_ml_print_connections

Answer (score 1):

You can use uvm_ml_phase -run connect. after this phase the ports are connected and you can view the uvm_ml tree and all the ports relations via design browser.